# Why is etree.tostring() not working for different methods?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I'm learning XML and am trying the following exercise code:

```
root = etree.XML('<html><head/><body><p>Hello<br/>World</p></body></html>')
etree.tostring(root, method='xml')
print(etree.tostring(root))
etree.tostring(root, method='html') 
print(etree.tostring(root))
etree.tostring(root, method='text') 
print(etree.tostring(root))
```

In the exercise, it says if I do this, I should be getting 3 differently formatted output strings for root: xml, html and text. However, I'm just getting 3 XML-formatted outputs.

What am I missing here? Was I supposed to import something? My suspicion is that something is amiss with the etree.XML assignment part, but as I say: I'm just following directions here. What do people think is amiss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of the `tostring()` calls are indeed different but are lost each time, and you're instead printing the *same* expression three times.  (Be aware that `tostring()` is **returning a result, *not* modifying its arguments in place**.)

If you instead run this script:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML('<html><head/><body><p>Hello<br/>World</p></body></html>')
print(etree.tostring(root, method='xml'))
print(etree.tostring(root, method='html'))
print(etree.tostring(root, method='text'))
```

You'll get the output you expect:

```
<html><head/><body><p>Hello<br/>World</p></body></html>
<html><head></head><body><p>Hello<br>World</p></body></html>
HelloWorld
```

Comment: Umm, now I'm getting an error pointing to the "from lxml import etree" error saying "No module named lxml". It seems to work if I leave that line out though. Thanks for your help.